# How to generate the numbers between given range in random order using BASH. Each number should appear only once

Tags: bash

The number should appear only once and it should not be repeated.

It would be better if the script will accept two integers as command-line arguments and generate random integers between them.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can use shuf and seq for this. Accept the lower limit and upper limits as two parameters. Use these with seq to count from the lower to the upper limit. Redirect the output from the seq output back into shuf to get a random list. So in a script called randnums.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
shuf <<< $(seq $1 $2)
```

Run with:

```
./randnums.sh 5 10
```